# How to make table expandable to hide by default

Tags: php, jquery, css, html-table, expand

I using flat-responsive-admin template, but i have a table with expandable by default but what i want in default it hide all the data when user click's it will expand,pic show you its in expand in default like this:

[image]

I want like this in default like this:

[image]

is possible to do it? Below is the code can anyone help me out the line responsible for expand is `data-grouping="expandable"` but I don't know what is line for make it hide by default:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-nomargin table-striped dataTable dataTable-grouping dataTable-noheader" data-grouping="expandable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Mobile</th>
<th class='hidden-350'>Email</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Contact Type</td>
<td><?php print $totalsqlcontacttypemobilecorporate; ?></td>
<td><?php print $totalsqlcontacttypecorporateemail; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Are you using a framework, plugin or something for expandable tables or just jQuery?

Comment: yes it's with the template

Comment: Which framework are you using? Every framework works has it's own way of expressing itself.